# listing folders and files on remote account

Tags: php

I need php script for listing folders and files on remote account; like in this example (this screen is in localhost)

[image: listing folders and files]

I also tried this code, but it doesn't work

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)) {
echo "Connected as $ftp_server\n";
} else {
echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user_name\n";
}

$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "css/") or die("Couldn't read to $ftp_server");
echo $contents;
```

Unfortunately in console I see

```
Connected as atollosrl@ftp.atollosrl.com
Couldn't read to ftp.atollosrl.com
```

when code is arrived to

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "css/") or die("Couldn't read to $ftp_server");
```

it die.

---

Solved.
Change from `ftp_nlist` to `ftp_rawlist` now this code work :)

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)) {
echo "Connected as $ftp_server\n";
} else {
echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user_name\n";
}

$contents = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, "/") or die("Couldn't read to $ftp_server");

echo $contents;
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You might want to put that in your original question then, because a) it shows you've attempted a solution yourself, and b) it will make it clear to answerers that you're doing it over an FTP connection.

Comment: @halfer I edited question as Gordon suggests, now I will write what problem I'm ecountering! Thanks!

Comment: @halfer: with that code I don't see nothing, I add code and this problem in first post, can you re-open this thread?

Comment: @GordonM please can you vote too for reopen my question? I don't attract spam or other but I would like to have only a solution for my problem.

Comment: I voted already.  It's up to the rest of the community whether this is good enough as a question now.

Comment: @halfer In console I see this: `Connected as atollosrl@ftp.atollosrl.com
Couldn't read to ftp.atollosrl.com` now I add this in first post

Comment: OK, now you have something to debug! It looks like your logon was fine, but your last FTP command was not. Maybe that directory does not exist? (Yes please, any time you discover something new, update the question itself, thanks).

Comment: Also, look at the manual for the `nlist` command and see what the expected return parameter is. See if what this function does is suitable for what you are trying to do. Finally, try an FTP client to see what folders are visible in the root folder - maybe this folder is not at the root level?

Comment: I also tried to change `css/` with `atollo2014/assets/css` when I can see in index.php, but unfortunately it doens't work too. Now I see yet `ftp_nlist` and I hope to resolve this problem :)

Comment: @halfer now try with `ftp_rawlist` and `passive mode`

Comment: Your question now seems unfinished. You "try" with those two functions, what happened? Would you update the code block to show where you added them?

Comment: I done :) Can you close this thread? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    exec("dir", $output, $return);
    echo "Dir returned $return, and output:\n";
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

For windows and some unix machines

Comment: I'd recommend that you don't post answers to poor questions.  As for your particular solution, it's extremely insecure, and completely ignores PHP's built in file and directory handling libraries.

Comment: He didn't bother about security of the php code, It just fetched his requirement. You shouldn't be down voting my answer like that.

Comment: If you read my comment you'd know I'd downvoted it for several reasons, lack of security being only one.